# Finding $\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\sqrt{x-1} + 2}{x+3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having problems with this example. What are all the ways I can determine if the lim tends towards positive or negative infinity without using derivatives?

> EX: Evaluate each of the following. If the limit does not exists state
>   so. If the limit is infinite then state whether the values tend
>   towards positive or negative infinity.

$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\sqrt {x-1}+2}{x+3}$$

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\sqrt{x+1}$?

Comment: well plus 2. Im not an expert at entering questions on this website.

Comment: It looks like the radical is over just the $x$. It sounds like you are saying it should be over the $x-2$. Is that right? Part of the help you'll get on SE is help formatting and asking questions.

Comment: I think he means $\frac {\sqrt{x-1}+2}{x+3}$

Comment: its sqrt{x-1} + 2 all divided by x+3

Comment: OK - so copy my formatting into your question.

Comment: edited question with mathjax

Comment: Now we can help you. Do you have any idea where to begin with this?

Comment: Thanks guys!!! well I think I could build a table of for limit approaching 3 from the - and + side but I feel like doing it this way will give me an answer for both positive and negative infinity.

Comment: You should be able to do this without a graphing calculator, *but* it does help to visualize what's going on. An online graphing calculator I like is https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: it doesn't exists/ its unbounded??, but if it does exists, what would I do about finding the infinity it tends towards?

Answer (score 1):

Try the limit by first substituting $x:=3$ and see if the function can be evaluated.

$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\sqrt {x-1}+2}{x+3}= \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\sqrt {3-1}+2}{3+3}=  \frac{\sqrt {2}+2}{6}\approx 0.569$$

This is the value for your limit. The graph shows the function to be continuous at this point. **It does *not* tend toward infinity.**

[image: Limit graph]

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\sqrt {x-1}+2}{x+3}$$
Put x=2.9
$$ \frac{\sqrt {2.9-1}+2}{2.9+3}=.57$$
put x=3.01
$$\frac{\sqrt {3.01-1}+2}{3.01+3}=.563$$

answer approaches .569

put x=2.9
$$\frac{\sqrt {2.9-1}+2}{2.9+3}$$
Take negative value for square root 
answer = 0.105

Put x=3.01
$$\frac{\sqrt {3.01-1}+2}{3.01+3}$$
Take Negative value 
Answer =0.09
Answer Approaches 0.1 for negative values

Comment: does that mean its only approaching positive infinity?

Comment: Since  we take positive value for $$\sqrt {x-1}$$ Try by taking Negative values

Comment: it gives a non real answer, im assuming that means the limit is only going towards positive infinity?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: -2.9 for x. The sqaure root cause it to be an unreal answer.

Comment: In your Question x approaches positive 3 but if you put -2.9 it will result in a imaginary number

Comment: It only becomes imaginary when $x<1$. The limit is as $x$ goes to 3.

Comment: @ChrisManning This limit does not tend toward infinity.

Comment: @ChrisManning This limit does not tend toward infinity. The question only states *if* the limit tends to infinity. For example, try graphing the limit as $x$ goes to $0$ of $3/x$. You'll see the line rise sharply as you approach from the right, and drop sharply as you approach from the left. There is no single limit. The one approaches + infinity and the other negative infinity.

Comment: The question in the OP is now completely different from what it started out to be.

Answer (score 0):

I would give hint this will help you understand better.

$x-3= (\sqrt {x+1} + 2)(\sqrt {x+1} - 2)$

And x is not exactly 3.

Comment: Why this question has been modified 3 times everytime diff value.

Comment: The answer is for the question before modification